# Get a sub property of a component in Delphi using RTTI

Tags: delphi, properties, components, rtti

I would like to access the following property using RTTI

```
MyComponent1.Property['variable'].SubProperty
```

I would like something like that:

```
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Typ: TRttiType;
  SubTyp: TRttiType;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
  SubProp: TRttiProperty;
begin
  Ctx:= TRttiContext.Create;
  Typ:= Ctx.GetType(MyComponent1.ClassInfo);
  Prop:= Typ.GetProperty('Property['variable'].Subproperty') //not possible
  Prop.SetValue(MyComponent1.Property['variable'],'500');
end;
```

Basically I want to access a subproperty of my component and I have only strings, so I cannot use `Typ:=Ctx.GetType(MyComponent1.ClassInfo)` and then `Prop:=Typ.GetProperty('Property['variable'].Subproperty')` this is not allowed. Attention in the fact that there is a paramenter for the first property. I guess I have to obtain this first property and then somehow the second property, because I cannot use this property1"."property2
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are really trying to achieve here? I suspect the final answer will be recursion :)

Comment: My goal is to set a value for the SubProperty, for example: `MyComponent1.Property['variable'].SubProperty`
But in my code I have a lot of components and properties, so I have to check first MyComponent and then get the property Property['variable'] and then somehow I would like to change SubProperty, but I cannot use `subProp:= Prop.getProperty` or `Typ.getProperty('Property['variable'].subProperty')`

Comment: You can remove the TRttiContext.Create and Ctx.Free lines

Comment: I also don't really understand your question.

Comment: Basically I want to access a subproperty of my component and I have only strings, so I cannot use `Typ:=Ctx.GetType(MyComponent1.ClassInfo)` and then Prop:= `Typ.GetProperty('Property['variable'].Subproperty')` this is not allowed. Attention in the fact that there is a paramenter for the first property. I guess I have to obtain this first property and then somehow the second property, because I cannot use this property1"."property2

Answer (score 0):

Index properties as all other properties (except direct references to object fields) just a shortcut to `getXXX` and `setXXX` methods.

Try that way:

1. Get all indexed properties of `Ctx.GetType(MyComponent1.ClassInfo)` with [`GetDeclaredIndexedProperties`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetDeclaredIndexedProperties) or [`GetIndexedProperties`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetIndexedProperties)
2. Search desired `Property` in returned array of [`TRttiIndexedProperty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiIndexedProperty_Properties) instances.
3. Get write method description object from [`WriteMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiIndexedProperty.WriteMethod) property of `TRttiIndexedProperty` object found.
4. Get method parameters description if you need it with [`GetParameters`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.GetParameters) call.
5. Call [`Invoke`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke) method of method description object with constructed parameter(s) list to set a property value.

**Update**

This works only in Delphi versions from XE2 and above.

In previous versions indexed properties can be adopted for RTTI only using things like discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491308/delphi-rtti-for-indexed-properties-in-2010).

Comment: Could you give a bit of code for that? I am quite confused how to accomplished it...

Comment: Which version of Delphi you use? RTTI support for indexed properties exists only since XE2 ...

Comment: I have Delphi version 2010

Comment: Another thing is that I may be misunderstood your question. Did you mean that you want to access inner property value by supplying just a string which describes access path to the inner property?

Comment: Yes, I have only strings and I would like to access the property, but I get problem when a property in inside another property.

Comment: If indexed properties like in your example is not an issue for you task and you can ignore them, just use recursive function to reach desired level step by step.