# TControl (child) to TObject and set its Parent property via RTTI or SetXXXXXXProperty

Tags: delphi, properties, rtti

Currently doing some research on RTTI in delphi.

The problem that arises is the following.

For this example I have a TPanel component (created from code and the owner is passed by the invoke method) Now the TPanel is cast to a TObject (to keep the methods I use generic).

Now I try to set that property via the SetXXXXXXProp function (XXXXXX is any of the following (ord, variant, str, method.... basically I tried all of the SetProperty functions.)

But for some odd reason the message I receive is that there is no Parent property.
How can I set my Parent property??

So I hope any of you can give me a 'Pointer' in the right direction.

```
class procedure TComponentsCreator.AddParent(obj, parent : TObject);
var
  count : integer;
  propList: PPropList;
  I: Integer;

  method : TMethod;
begin

  count := GetPropList(obj, propList);

  for I := 0 to count -1 do
    begin

      WriteLn(propList[i]^.Name);

      if (CompareStr(LowerCase(String(propList[i]^.Name)), LowerCase('Parent')) = 0) then
        begin
          SetObjectProp(obj, String(propList[i]^.Name), parent);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Depending on what your problem is, but there's probably no need to use RTTI at all, just use TControl.Parent.

Comment: Why won't you show the code that demonstrates the problem. Are we now expected to guess what you did?

Comment: Your right David I'll fetch it right away :-)

Comment: You mean count-1 in the for loop?

Comment: David why immediatly down my post??? Within 2 minutes of your message i've posted my code... can't a person forget something or what?

Comment: @lurd That is not the problem here. The list is unsorted but parent isn't showing in anyway.

Comment: Yes I know, that is why that was a comment. No need to show invalid code though.

Comment: Changed the for loop :)

Comment: This page gave the correct fix for my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948114/get-a-sub-property-of-a-component-in-delphi-using-rtti?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old style RTTI which was designed for the .dfm streaming mechanism. When you call `GetPropList` the list returned contains the published properties. You are looking for `Parent` which is  public but not published.

You could use the new style RTTI to achieve this but that would seem to be unnecessary. RTTI is needed when the member or type that you wish to operate on is not known at compile time. However, you do know the member. It is `TControl.Parent`. So you can write

```
(obj as TControl).Parent := parent;
```

If for some reason, you felt compelled to use RTTI, then the simplest way to write the code that I can find is:

```
procedure SetControlParent(obj, parent: TObject);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  typ := ctx.GetType(obj.ClassType);
  prop := typ.GetProperty('Parent');
  prop.SetValue(obj, parent);
end;
```

I've omitted any error checking here, but I expect that you would not do the same in real code.

---

As a minor aside, your call to `CompareStr` is needlessly complex. If you wish to use case insensitive comparison use `CompareText`. If you wish to compare for equality use `SameText`. You could replace that code more clearly and simply like this:

```
if SameText(propList[I]^.Name, 'Parent') then
```

Comment: As i've already stated in my previous comment. I've already used the fix from this link I've found on stackoverlow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948114/get-a-sub-property-of-a-component-in-delphi-using-rtti?rq=1

Comment: Hard to see how that question relates to this one. Also very hard to see why you want to use RTTI for something that you know at compile time.

Comment: In the case of a TPanel I know that at realtime but if i use multiple other components then I would have found myself in rewriting and checking everything for relations to a TControl/TWinControl. That is something i'm not going to do. Anyways everything works fine now as it should.

Comment: You don't need to know that it is a panel. But you do know that it is a `TControl`. Because otherwise `Parent` is meaningless. So you do know what you need to know at compile time.